# Select data from database based on drop-down list not working

Tags: c#, .net, database

I want to select values from the database based on a drop-down list. My database contains tables with fields values: `id(primary key),name,fullname,depat`.

My `webform1.aspx` page contains a drop-down list, `Gridview` and `SqlDatasource`.

This is my `Webform1.aspx.cs` code:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ztvConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table1 where name=depat", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

No data is shown after selecting values from the drop-down list. Where is the error?

Comment: Are you actually getting an error, or are you just not getting the results you expected? Is there a reason for saving the selected value to `s`? It isn't being used in the rest of your Event Handler that I see.

Answer (score 1):

Reading from your code, what you want to do is fill **GridView1** with data from Table1 where **name=depat**, is it really what you wants? Maybe you can make it clearer on what you want.

If you want to get the data based on the selected value, then you should make it:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table1 where name='" + s + "'", con);
```

But I strongly suggest you use Parameterized Query, create a SqlCommand first

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE name = @name", conn)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
cmd.Parameter["@name"].Value = s;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to get all the data for a specific department:

```
string s = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();

//SqlConnection...

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE depat = @depat", conn)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@depat", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
cmd.Parameter["@depat"].Value = s;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: thanks for your Response.My aim is that when selecting dept in Dropdown list the GridView show only the id,name,fullname belongs to that Dept only.

Comment: I guess Ruly has suggested an answer to your question. You are storing the selected value from dropdown list in string s right. so if now you have selected depat from dropdownlist then Ruly's query gives you the data back which belongs to that depat.

Answer (score 0):

Just to rule out the obvious, when you execute the sql statement "SELECT * FROM Table1 where name=depat" in Management Studio you get records returned?

Answer (score 0):

i believed Ruly got the answers=)

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string s = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ztvConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table1 where name=@name", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", s);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
}
```